# Nicknames for dogs in Peru

Tags: culture, nature-and-wildlife, peru

While hiking in Peru, a stray dog joined our group for about 2 days. Our guide gave it a nickname, let's pretend it was "Charlie." When we asked about it he said that most animals in their culture had a common nickname. For example, all dogs are "Charlie," all pigs are "Henry" and so on. Does anyone know what these names are? I've forgotten. I'm particularly interested in the nickname for dog, but would love to hear any that you know to make this question appealing to more readers.

Comment: I've adjusted the title to restrict it to dogs for now, otherwise it's very likely to be closed as too broad. Ideally someone will provide a list anyway with these names.  However there's still a chance people may close as off-topic or unclear - it might have just been that guide's set of nicknames, for all we know.

Comment: I think this would be better on http://spanish.stackexchange.com as it really seems to be about language.  While it may have arisen while traveling, I have a hard time imagining a situation in which another traveler would need to know this - and the whole purpose of this site is to collect questions and answers which may be of use to future visitors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: It could be that you are talking about "Firulais" http://www.cronica.com.py/2020/02/09/la-historia-firulais-donde-viene-nombre/